# How to deal with inconsistent/unknown list length's

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently scraping data, I am not sure how to deal with the inconsistent list lengths

the raw data look like this is as follows: `"Group 2, Cheltenham, Jul 5 - 8 2021, County Championship`

or

if it missing an element like this: `"Newport, Jul 5 - 8 2021, Second Eleven Championship"`

I then split the string it by ",".

```
#This list is correct because it has all possible elements. 
['Group Name', 'Location', 'Date', 'Cup Name']

#This list is in-correct because it is missing the "Group name" element
['Location', 'Date', 'Cup Name']
```

I was thinking of doing an if statement on the len of that list.

```
if len(list) == 4:
  return {
           "group_name": list[0]
           "location": list[1]
           "date": list[2]
           "cup_name": list[3]
         }

if len(list) == 3:
  return {
           "location": list[0]
           "date": list[1]
           "cup_name": list[2]
         }
```

but I am worried that perhaps instead of "Group Name" not being on the list another element would missing. is there a way to get around this?

Comment: why 4 is correct and 3 is incorrect?

Comment: It is missing the "Group Name" element.

Comment: The problem is not clear. Please explain

Comment: `if all( e in yourlist for e in ['Group Name', 'Location', 'Date', 'Cup Name']): ... do smth`

Comment: You could perhaps use regular expressions to validate the individual components. For example, if `Group Name` always starts with `"Group"` that is easy to test for, and the dates should be easy to pick out (if there). When there are less than the expected 4 pieces of data, you need some way of determining which pieces are missing.

Comment: @JohnColeman Yes. That's a great solution thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You could try sequence unpacking with a star:

```
*group_name, location, date, cup_name = list  # NOTE: list is the name of a builtin, you should really use a different variable name

if group_name:  # group name present
    # note that you need to extract the first item from the length-1 list to get the actual group name
    return {'group_name': group_name[0], 'location': location, 'date': date, 'cup_name': cup_name}
# group name absent
return {'location': location, 'date': date, 'cup_name': cup_name}
```